# How to clear a range of cells using "index numbers"-notation

Tags: excel, vba

I want to clear the contents of all cells in between B30 (upper left corner) and Fx (bottom right) where x is a variable to determine the bottom row.
Therefore I've tried to use index numbers notation along the lines of:

```
Worksheets(1).Range("Cells(30, 2):Cells(x, 6)").ClearContents
```

However, I can't get this to work. Clearly I don't get the syntax on this.
Thankful for any help.

Comment: Use a `,` instead of `:`. Also, no `"`.

Comment: Also `Range` will look at the first worksheet in tab order, `Cells` will look at the currently active sheet - need to fully qualify all range/cell references.

Comment: Using a [With...End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement) block will make it easier - `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1): .Range(.Cells(30, 2), .Cells(x, 6)).ClearContents: End With`

Comment: Range(Cells(30, 2),Cells(x, 6)).ClearContents did the trick. Thanks alot!